# AppLoving and MoPub

Tags: mopub, applovin

I had a MoPub account but now the company was acquired by AppLovin.

The question is: what happened to my account and all my data?

Is it all deleted? Or transfered to AppLovin?

Is there a way to delete my account or contact MoPub? (I can't find any email to contact them).

Is I enter to the MoPub page it redirects to AppLovin and there it ends, so I can search nothing. That is, I can't access.

I still receiving some MoPub emails so I need to resolve this. Please help.

Comment: They closed their portal. You are not able to access your reporting and your payment history. You received emails with deadlines. You user account is already created in AppLovin, but no placements are created. You basically need to start all over again.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.

Yes, they sent emails. But I didn't delete the account and all my data, the question is:

Has the new AppLovin account all my personal data? Or the account is blank?

I tried to login with old credentials but AppLovin says my account doesn't exist, so, it could be that all my personal data is gone along with Mopub?

Comment: The account is blank

Comment: That could mean that all my data is deleted. Thanks for helping!